# jquery ajax post says xxx not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was trying to call eBay FindProducts API using AJAX (`post` request) but was stuck at the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts. Origin http://localhost.com/test.php is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My code:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts',
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
    contentType: 'application/x-javascript',
    crossDomain : true,
    data: {
        'X-EBAY-API-APP-ID' : 'ebayAppId', 
        'X-EBAY-API-VERSION': '771', 
        'X-EBAY-API-SITEID': '0', 
        'X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING': 'NV', 
        'X-EBAY-API-RESPONSE-ENCODING': 'json',
        'QueryKeywords' : '753759971632',
        'MaxEntries' : '3'
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert((data));
    }
})
```

How can I get through this error.

I tried setting `dataType : jsonp` (I know XML is being retrieved, but to workaround the error I set it to jsonP). It works but jQuery was unable to parse the XML as the json response was expected.

Comment: *"I tried setting dataType : jsonP"* - it won't work because JSONP is **not** XML and vice versa. try to check if ebay supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) so that you can read the XML.

Comment: You might have to do this on the server-side. You would make an ajax call to your server, passing along any information from the page that you need. Then, hit the api in php using something like curl.

Comment: Hi joseph,thanks for your reply. I understand that json is not xml and vice-versa(see my post in () after I tried setting dataType : jsonP ).
If eBay doesnt suppport CORS , is there a way to do this?
is there a way to retreive the xml even after setting the dataType to jsonp or script(i see fromt he browser console that the xml is being retreived, but jquery was not able to parse it.)?

lbstr - thansk  for your reply, I am aware of the way to impelment this using curl/php :) . i want to chekc if this can be done ont he client side.

Comment: albin's solution will solve this problem, however, do you want your appid open to the public?

Comment: appid  being public is fine, but i dont know why jquery was not able to parse the reponse, and ajax returns an error!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add `&responseencoding=JSON` to your URL you will get the response as JSON according to [docs](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html#URLExamples)

**UPDATE**
[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sbPbL/3/). What I've done is that I changed to `dataType:'jsonp'` added `jsonp:'callbackname'`. Because jQuery by default calls the callback parameter `callback`, but eBay expect it to be called `callbackname`. What you have to do is add your parameters to the data map. Make sure you use the correct parameter names, check the docs and use the URL method not the header method. Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont think its working cuz, if you see my ajax call, am already sending X-EBAY-API-RESPONSE-ENCODING': 'json',

Comment: funny thing is that i was watchign the request and response headers/params

i was able to retreive a json response, but still the error : Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:

Comment: Yeah I just saw that. But however your passing it as a parameter, if you try passing it as a header and when I tried I saw that it is case sensitive in the [docs](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html#HTTPHeaderExamples) they are using JSON.

Comment: i guess retreiving the response as Json is working fine. but the problem is that i am receiving the error : Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:
I am not sure where i made a mistake.

Comment: Ok, I still think you should move all `X-EBAY-API-...` from `data` to `headers`. Another question, why are you sending a `POST`? When I try from my HTTP-client the response is empty when I'm sending `POST` but not when sending `GET`.

Comment: "If you are using the HTTP POST method, call-specific values are specified in your HTTP message." Hmm. To be honest, this whole topic seems to start smelling like "read the manual" etc.

Comment: if i move to headers, the request url will not be built with the concerned params. resulting in an error!
I tried GET as well, But its the same error.

Comment: response is never a success, its always an error. 
 
however, How do i get the json response into a variable? Even on "error", can i capture the response? if so what method/property of the response object enables me to do that.

Comment: [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sbPbL/3/). What I've done is that I changed to `dataType:'jsonp'` added `jsonp:'callbackname'`. Because jQuery by default calls the callback parameter callback, but eBay expect it to be called 'callbackname'. What you have to do is add your parameters to the data map. Make sure you use the correct parameter names, check the [docs](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html#URLExamples) and use the URL method not the header method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this , here are my findings :

error : Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts&callbackname=jQuery17208283274378627539_1337642910066&appid=appid&version=771&siteid=0&responseencoding=JSON&QueryKeywords=753759971632&MaxEntries=3". 

also i can confirm all the params in the data map are good, i am able to see the response in the browser console. but error was being executed after the request. no way i could capture this response text. success(response){
response.responseText is always null
}

Comment: albin : Did you notice that in your working example the response.responseText is undefined, though it returns success! This is where i am exactly stuck at!

Comment: Albin: Many thanks i got it to work. Thanks for your example. 
I was expecting response.responseText to hold the object, but response itelf is the response JSON from eBay. I was able to print it to the textarea by doing ,
$("#eBayXMLResponse").val(JSON.stringify(object,null,4));
JSON.stringify is a nice method to convert json obj to string. and other params are for formatting with '4' indent.



Summary:


Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#dataType) documentation, you can use jsonp and still have a different return type to be parsed.

> multiple, space-separated values: As of jQuery 1.5, jQuery can convert a dataType from what it received in the Content-Type header to what you require. For example, if you want a text response to be treated as XML, use "text xml" for the dataType. You can also make a JSONP request, have it received as text, and interpreted by jQuery as XML: "jsonp text xml." Similarly, a shorthand string such as "jsonp xml" will first attempt to convert from jsonp to xml, and, failing that, convert from jsonp to text, and then from text to xml.

So basically all you have to do is change your `dataType` line of code to this:

```
dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "jsonp text xml" : "xml",
```

Or you can add a `&responseencoding=JSON` parameter to your URL, as stated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10692959/578843).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the doc looks promising, but doesnt seem to work.

also i appended the responseencoding to Json in my url, dint work.

however i am getting an error when i try to use datatype: "jsonp text xml"

Comment: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: {"http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts&responseencoding=JSON&callback=jQuery17205092789542395622_1337636555119&X-EBAY-API-APP-ID=appId&X-EBAY-API-VERSION=771&X-EBAY-API-SITEID=0&X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING=NV&X-EBAY-API-RESPONSE-ENCODING=json&QueryKeywords=753759971632&MaxEntries=3&_=1337636556130".}

Comment: Remove the contentType option, seems like that one is messing things up. (Why did you set it to application/x-javascript?)

Comment: sorry , i removed the content-type, was testign out some thing. however removal of content-type doesnt seem to help.

Comment: It is just a warning, not an error. It shouldn't break your code. (The warning is because the server didn't answer with a proper MIME Type, but shouldn't matter too much.) Anyway, it is better to receive your data as JSON, as told in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10692959/578843 . (The trick I showed, is actually kinda a hack / workaround for what you want.)

Comment: Ok, How do i get the json response into a variable? Even on "error", can i capture the response? if so what method/property of the response object enables me to do that.
Thanks a ton for your time.

Comment: The fact you have an error, is completely different. Reading the documentation you should put those X-EBAY-API-* variables into the HEADer (as also stated in the documentation). Apart from that, you can also just include those values in your URL rather that put them in your request headers (see here: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html#StandardURLParameters ).

Comment: just retreived the errorTHrown :
Error: jQuery17207783316969871521_1337639319042 was not called
No idea what it means!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got thi to work by doing 2 things, Thanks to Albin.

I changed to dataType:'jsonp' added jsonp:'callbackname'. Because jQuery by default calls the callback parameter callback, but eBay expect it to be called 'callbackname'. XML was not working due to CRO problem with eBay(need to confirm though.)

Used the chrome console to debug the object retreived, converetd to string using JSON.Stringify().

Hope this helps somebody!

Cheers,
Rajesh